# Detect iBeacon when app is killed swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, core-location, ibeacon

I need to do something if iPhone detect (beacon in background) with UUID: "3E06945C-F54A-4BE4-ABB2-79764DA6AC6F" so I am trying to do this, in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert], categories: nil))

    initBeaconManager()
    //Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    //Fabric.with([Appsee.self])
    return true
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("Application will terminate")
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    isInForeground = false
    isInBackground = true
    extendBackgroundTime()
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    isInForeground = true
    isInBackground = false
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "initCarPlaceNotification"), object: nil)
}
func extendBackgroundTime() {
    if backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
        // Still running
        return
    }
    else {
        backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "Ranging", expirationHandler: { () in
            // Background task expired by iOS
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
            self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
        });

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async { //
            if !self.isInForeground {
                while true {
                    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
                }
            }
        }
    }

func initBeaconManager() {
    let beaconsUUIDs = ["1":"3E06945C-F54A-4BE4-ABB2-79764DA6AC6F"]

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    if (locationManager!.responds(to: #selector(CLLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization))) {
        locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    locationManager!.delegate = self
    locationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true

    for (key, value) in beaconsUUIDs {
        let beaconUUID:UUID = UUID(uuidString: value)!
        let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID, identifier: "reg-\(key)")
        locationManager!.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
        locationManager!.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
    }

    locationManager!.startUpdatingHeading()
    locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()

}
extension AppDelegate {
    func rangeForAllBeacons(_ beacons:[CLBeacon]) {
    if beacons[0].proximityUUID == UUID(uuidString: "3E06945C-F54A-4BE4-ABB2-79764DA6AC6F") {
        displayNotification("work fine..")
    }
}

extension AppDelegate:CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    if !isInForeground {
        extendBackgroundTime()
    }

    print(beacons)

    for beacon in beacons {
        if beacon.rssi < -20 {
            nearbyBeacons.append(beacon)
        }
    }

    if firstRegionDetected == "" {
        firstRegionDetected = region.identifier
    } else if firstRegionDetected == region.identifier {
        rangeForAllBeacons(nearbyBeacons)
        nearbyBeacons = []
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, for region: CLRegion) {
    if isInBackground {
        extendBackgroundTime()
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. On the info.plist I use

```
Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
```

and

```
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
```

Comment: Why aren't you requesting "always" authorization?  You also need to set `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates' to `true`.  Also, you shouldn't start ranging the beacon until you have entered the beacon region

Comment: Ok I set to "always" and allowBackgroundLocationUpdates to true, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get a call to `didDetermineState` for your beacon region when your app is in the foreground? - That is the first step

Comment: Of course, as you can see when app going to 'applicationDidEnterBackground' func didDeterminate state run extendBackgroundTimer()

Comment: I can see that is what your code says, but I have no idea what is actually happening.  The only problem description you have given is "it doesn't work".  You need to give more detail; do you actually get a beacon entry event in the foreground?  After entering the region does beacon ranging work.  Then, do you get a beacon entry event in the background?  Then does ranging work?   You will only be able to range for up to 180 seconds in the background before your app will be killed by iOS

Comment: Ok so, In foreground all works fine, when I click one time "home button" also work fine, when I kill app it doesn't work. I don't know why, how can I test it? Can I only restart bluetooth to test?

Comment: If you killed the app then it is dead.  If you want things to keep running,  don't kill it

Comment: Ok, so it can't work when I kill app?

Comment: Ok bo what when I need to display notification when app is killed?

Comment: I think iOS will display your app icon on the lock screen if the device enters a monitored region; The user can tap the icon to launch your app

Comment: Ok so my code can work when user enter region? Or how can I test it when I am all time in region, restart bluetooth?

Comment: Yes, or turn the beacon off until you exit the region

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. :)